# Counting the amount of relations to one table to another

Tags: sql, sqlite

Very hard to create a good title for this.

Given the table `products`

```
productID
---------
892
583
388
```

And the table `purchases`

```
customerID   productID
----------   ---------
56           892
97           388
56           583
56           388
97           583
```

How would I go about getting a table of all the costumers that have bought *all* products?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select customerId
from purchases
group by customerId
having count(distinct productID) = (select count(*) from products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` clause with `HAVING` :

```
SELECT pr.customerID 
FROM products p INNER JOIN
     purchases pr
     on pr.productID = p.productID
GROUP BY pr.customerID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pr.productID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products);
```